# How can I join two dataframes in pandas that have different no of rows and different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a pandas DataFrame by merging 2 DataFrames consisting of different number of rows.
I have attached my code below. Im trying to join these 2 dataframes together but I'm getting an error stating:
`KeyError: 'Number of Mutations'`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

df1= pd.DataFrame({"Mutations": ["A>T", "A>G", "A>C", "T>A", "T>C", "T>G", "C>A", "C>T", "C>G", "G>A", "G>T", "G>C"], 
                   "Number of Mutations": [213, 659, 281, 204, 627, 208, 351, 1004, 360, 1054, 323, 351]})

df2= pd.DataFrame({"Number of Bases":["A = 42239", "T = 55005", "G = 46060" , "C = 45422"]})

mdf=df1.merge(df2, on= "Number of Mutations" , how="outer")
print(mdf)
```

Comment: What do you try to merge on? What are the conditions? What is your desired output? You get this error because there is no column "Number of Mutations" in df2, which you specified in the merge.

Comment: my desired output is to align both the dataframes together so the columns are as follows: Mutations, Number of Mutations, Number of bases. so i dont exactly know where shall I merge it since the columns in both the dataframes are different and the rows are of different sizes as well

Comment: show us your desired output dataframe for this example. It is not clear to me how it should look since there is no rule on how to combine the rows.

Comment: Mutations, Number of Mutations, Number of Bases
A>T,           213,                             A= 42239,      
A>G,          659,                             T= 55005,
A>C,          281,                             G= 46060,
T>A,          204,                              C= 45422,
T>G,          208,
T>C,          627,
C>A,         351,
C>T,          1004,
C>G,          360, 
G>A,         1054,
G>T,           323,
G>C,           351,

Comment: Please paste that into your question with proper format.

Comment: I tried to find the right format but could not however this should be good enough to interpret, I want 3 Column headers: Mutations, Number of Mutations, Number of Bases, with the last column having only 4 rows and the rest having 12

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to combine these df's in the first place, since the rows aren't connected at all. But if you just want to align them next to each other, you want to use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(out)
```

```
   Mutations  Number of Mutations Number of Bases
0        A>T                  213       A = 42239
1        A>G                  659       T = 55005
2        A>C                  281       G = 46060
3        T>A                  204       C = 45422
4        T>C                  627             NaN
5        T>G                  208             NaN
6        C>A                  351             NaN
7        C>T                 1004             NaN
8        C>G                  360             NaN
9        G>A                 1054             NaN
10       G>T                  323             NaN
11       G>C                  351             NaN
```

If there are different indices and you just want to have df2 at the beginning till there is no more data, then you need to use reset_index() before you concat them.

```
out = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```